# Detect if an IP address is running a Bitcoin node

Tags: ip, bitcoin, cryptocurrency, bitcoind

Is there a way to detect if an IP address is running a Bitcoin node? Maybe I can extract the IP information from the blockchain somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do this.

Pretty reliable and relatively simple way is to get the list of Bitcoin nodes from  https://api.blockchair.com/bitcoin/nodes.
It is the JSON object that looks like:

```
{"data":{"nodes":{"1.234.63.142:8333":"version":"\/Satoshi:0.16.0\/","country":"KR","height":588031,"flags":1037},
"1.36.226.179:8333":{"version":"\/Satoshi:0.18.0\/","country":"HK","height":588031,"flags":1037},
"100.12.85.110:8333":{"version":"\/Satoshi:0.16.2\/","country":"US","height":588031,"flags":1037},
...
```

And then check if IP address in question is present in this list.

Comment: Like this answer even though I wonder if there is a solution which does not involve using third party services.

Comment: Other options are: run the Bitcoin node and use getaddr command to build own node list;
simple and unreliable - try to connect to port 8333/TCP of the host. There are ~600 of ~10000 nodes listening to other ports, also there may be hosts that have other services on port 8333.

Comment: For Bitcoin cash the url would be: https://api.blockchair.com/bitcoin-cash/nodes